# ffmpeg created video from images does not play in jwplayer

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jwplayer

I have created a video from images with ffmpeg. Created video plays fine in my local machine with vlc. But it does not play in jwplayer/any web player.

Commands used:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -r 1/4 -i image_%d.png -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf fps=fps=30 int_video.mp4

ffmpeg -i int_video.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -pix_fmt yuv420p final.mp4"
```

Information about the create video is as below:

```
        General
        Complete name                    : /home/oodles/git/picdeo/web-app/uservideos/admin/z4/username_admin__s3vidname_z4.mp4
        Format                           : MPEG-4
        Format profile                   : Base Media
        Codec ID                         : isom
        File size                        : 691 KiB
        Duration                         : 20s 34ms
        Overall bit rate                 : 282 Kbps
        Writing application              : Lavf55.12.100

        Video
        ID                               : 1
        Format                           : AVC
        Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
        Format profile                   : High@L3.0
        Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
        Format settings, ReFrames        : 4 frames
        Codec ID                         : avc1
        Codec ID/Info                    : Advanced Video Coding
        Duration                         : 20s 34ms
        Bit rate                         : 279 Kbps
        Nominal bit rate                 : 500 Kbps
        Width                            : 480 pixels
        Height                           : 360 pixels
        Display aspect ratio             : 4:3
        Frame rate mode                  : Constant
        Frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
        Color space                      : YUV
        Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
        Bit depth                        : 8 bits
        Scan type                        : Progressive
        Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.054
        Stream size                      : 683 KiB (99%)
        Writing library                  : x264 core 135 r2 f0c1c53
        Encoding settings                : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=1 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=500 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
```

How can I use ffmpeg to create a video that works in jwplayer?

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running?